# MongoDB aggregation: choose single document based on dates in subdocument

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

My collection, userresults, has documents which are unique by userref and sessionref together. A session has a selection of game results in a results array. I have already filtered the results to return those userresults documents which contain a result for game “Clubs”.

```
[{
    "userref": "AAA",
    "sessionref" : "S1",
    "results": [{
        "gameref": "Spades",
        "dateplayed": ISODate(2022-01-01T10:00:00),
        "score": 1000
    }, {
        "gameref": "Hearts",
        "dateplayed": ISODate(2022-01-02T10:00:00),
        "score": 500
    }, {
        "gameref": "Clubs",
        "dateplayed": ISODate(2022-01-05T10:00:00),
        "score": 200
    }]
}, {
    "userref": "AAA",
    "sessionref" : "S2",
    "results": [{
        "gameref": "Spades",
        "dateplayed": ISODate(2022-02-02T10:00:00),
        "score": 1000
    }, {
        "gameref": "Clubs",
        "dateplayed": ISODate(2022-05-02T10:00:00),
        "score": 200
    }]
}, {
    "userref": "BBB",
    "sessionref" : "S1",
    "results": [{
        "gameref": "Clubs",
        "dateplayed": ISODate(2022-01-05T10:00:00),
        "score": 200
    }]
}]
```

What I need to do within my aggregation is select the userresult document FOR EACH USER that contains the most recently played game of Clubs, ie in this case it will return the AAA/S2 document and the BBB/S1 document.

I’m guessing I need a group on the userref as a starting point, but then how do I select the rest of the document based on the most recent Clubs date?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you can try this aggregation pipeline:

- First I've used `$filter` to avoid `$unwind` into the entire collection. With this you can get only objects into the `results` array where the `gameref` is `Clubs`.
- Next stage is now the `$unwind` but in this case only with remaining documents, not the entire collection. Note that this stage will not pass to the next stage documents where there is no any `"gameref": "Clubs"`.
- Now `$sort` the remaining results by `dateplayed` to get the recent date at first position.
- And last `$group` using `$first` to get the data you want. As documents are sorted by `dateplayed`, you can get desired result.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "results": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$results",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$this.gameref",
              "Clubs"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$results"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "results.dateplayed": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$userref",
      "results": {
        "$first": "$results"
      },
      "sessionref": {
        "$first": "$sessionref"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fCkYm25CX9J)

Comment: Massively useful, thanks very much. Of course, I'd oversimplified so had to tweak it a bit, but this was a massive help to get me to the final solution. Top work!